# Reading data from two different array of json objects and keeping in third json array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have two arrays containing objects like the below:

```
json1[] = [{
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "speed": 15,
    "speedlimit": 10
}, {
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "speed": 15,
    "speedlimit": 10
}, {
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "speed": 15,
    "speedlimit": 10
}];

json2[] = [{
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "Brake": 15
}, {
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "Brake": 15
}, {
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "Brake": 15
}];
```

Using the above two objects I want to create a 3rd; `json3[]`. How can I do this?

Comment: json3[] should contain time, speed, speedlimit and brake data from first two objects

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that your variable names will cause you syntax errors as they cannot contain the `[]` characters.

Secondly, to achieve what you need you can simply use the `concat()` method:

```
var json3 = json1.concat(json2);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/upcfwj5c/)

Comment: it wont answers the problem.. there wont be correlation between time

Comment: I'm confused. Your question states that you just want to join them together. If thats not the case, please edit the question to state **exactly** what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: iam expecting json3[] to be containing following data :(

[{"time":"00:00:00", "speed":15, "speedlimit":10, "Brake":15},{"time":"00:00:00", "speed":15, "speedlimit":10, "Brake":15},{"time":"00:00:00", "speed":15, "speedlimit":10, "Brake":15}]

but concat gives folling op
[{"time":"00:00:00", "speed":15, "speedlimit":10, "Brake":15},{"time":"00:00:00", "speed":15, "speedlimit":10, "Brake":15},{"time":"00:00:00", "speed":15, "speedlimit":10, "Brake":15},
{"time":"00:00:00",  "Brake":15},{"time":"00:00:00",  "Brake":15},{"time":"00:00:00", "Brake":15}]